# Цикл в отдельный поток, вывод кода ответа сервера

Tags: c#, winforms

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
    {
        for (int k = Convert.ToInt32(textMinId.Text); k <= Convert.ToInt32(textMaxId.Text); k++)
                        {
                            uri = new Uri(textUrl.Text + dictionary[i] + extensions[u]);
                            try
                            {
                                HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
                                httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                this.Invoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
                                {
                                    UCProcess.Instance.dataResult.Rows.Add("file", uri, "error");
                                    UCProcess.Instance.progressBar1.Value++;
                                }));
                                continue;
                            }
                            this.Invoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
                            {
                                UCProcess.Instance.dataResult.Rows.Add("file", uri, httpWebResponse.StatusDescription);
                                UCProcess.Instance.progressBar1.Value++;
                            }));
                        }

    }));
```

Проверяю наличие файлов на сайте, как сделать вывод кода ответа сервера (200, 404, 301, 502 и т.д)? И как правильно вывести выполнение цикла в отдельном потоке? Если беру все под Invoke, то жалуется на continue, а сейчас если страница выдает код 200 - сразу цикл завершается.

Comment: Это у вас требование задания использовать только `Thread` или вы просто не знаете о существовании `Task` и `async/await`?

Comment: Не знаю( (символы)

Comment: Что означает это ваше `( (символы)`? Это ‍♂️?

Comment: Лимит на кол-во символов при ответе

Comment: Я вам примерчик накидал, см. [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples2/tree/master/WinFormsDownloadList)

Comment: Bulson, спасибо большое, Вам цены нет!

Comment: А могу ли я как-то использовать столько потоков, сколько я указал в форме?